# How can I switch kind of protocol that I prepared to work with?

Tags: android, kotlin, chirp

I understood that chirp use 16kHz-mono protocol for transmitter data in Android. Can I switch kind of protocol that I prepared to work with? And how it realise if it real?

p.s. Add links on [Chirp Android documentation](https://developers.chirp.io/docs/getting-started/android) and also [example on github](https://github.com/chirp/chirp-android-examples/tree/master/Kotlin/Messenger).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chirp config string is what configures the audio properties of the SDK. You can select different configs from https://developers.chirp.io/applications.

If you select ultrasonic from the dropdown box, you will notice the config string change. Copy and paste this into your app and the SDK will then use this ultrasonic protocol.

You can find more information on these pages

https://developers.chirp.io/docs/using-chirp/protocols

https://developers.chirp.io/docs/using-chirp/credentials

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I didn't pay attention to logs. I changed only config key. Sorry for this question